# Adding max range value on Google bar charts

Tags: jquery, google-visualization

I have generated a chart based on certain calculation.

I want to set the max value in x-axis as 5 instead of 3 and I want to set it as the max range since I know all the values will be below or equal to 5.

Here is my code:

```
 function drawStuff() {
        var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
            ['Category', 'value'],
            ["Transparency", <?=$final1?>],
            ["Relationships", <?=$final2?>],
            ["Understanding", <?=$final3?>],
            ["Shared Success", <?=$final4?>],
            ['Truth-Telling', <?=$final5?>]
        ]);

        var options = {
            title: 'Trust Self-Assessment',
            width: 800,
            legend: { position: 'none' },
            chart: { title: 'Trust Self-Assessment',
                subtitle: '' },
            bars: 'horizontal', // Required for Material Bar Charts.
            axes: {
                x: {
                    1: { side: 'top', label: 'Percentage'} // Top x-axis.
                }
            },
            bar: { groupWidth: "90%" }
        };

        var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('top_x_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
    };
```

**Here is the output:**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

there are a few options that can be used to set the range of an axis...

```
{hAxis,vAxis,hAxes.*,vAxes.*}.ticks
{hAxis,vAxis,hAxes.*,vAxes.*}.minValue
{hAxis,vAxis,hAxes.*,vAxes.*}.maxValue
{hAxis,vAxis,hAxes.*,vAxes.*}.viewWindowMode
```

however, none are supported by *Material* charts...

*Material* = `google.charts.Bar` -- `packages: ['bar']`

*Classic* = `google.visualization.BarChart` -- `packages: ['corechart']`

see --> [Tracking Issue for Material Chart Feature Parity](https://github.com/google/google-visualization-issues/issues/2143)

---

there is an option to style *Classic* charts **similar** to *Material*...

```
theme: 'material'
```

see following working snippet,
here, `hAxis.ticks` is used to set the range...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
    packages: ['corechart']
}).then(function () {
    var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Category', 'value'],
        ['Transparency', 3],
        ['Relationships', 1],
        ['Understanding', 1],
        ['Shared Success', 1],
        ['Truth-Telling', 1]
    ]);

    var options = {
        title: 'Trust Self-Assessment',
        width: 800,
        legend: { position: 'none' },
        vAxis: {
          title: 'Category'
        },
        hAxis: {
          ticks: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
        },
        chartArea: {
          left: 120
        },
        theme: 'material'
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('top_x_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="top_x_div"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it fixed like this:

```
    var options = {
            title: 'Trust Self-Assessment',
            width: 800,
            legend: { position: 'none' },
            chart: { title: 'Trust Self-Assessment',
                subtitle: '' },
            bars: 'horizontal', // Required for Material Bar Charts.
            axes: {
                x: {
                    1: { side: 'top', label: 'Percentage'}, // Top x-axis.
                    all: {
                        range: {
                            max: 5,
                            min: 0
                        }
                    }

                }
            },
            bar: { groupWidth: "90%" }
        };
```